# Can we use NSAutoreleasePool for a view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsautoreleasepool

I want to know is there any way to use `NSAutoreleasePool` through a view (just like we define something in `.h` file and `dealloc` them in dealloc method of .m file).
Is it possible?

Comment: What are you asking? Do you want to have a property/ivar of type `NSAutoreleasePool` in your class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this shouldn't be done.

From Apple's [autorelease pools](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) documentation:

> An autorelease pool should always be drained in the same context (such as the invocation of a method or function, or the body of a loop) in which it was created.

and the next paragraph

> Autorelease pools are used “inline.” There should typically be no reason why you should make an autorelease pool an instance variable of an object.

Comment: thank 4 your good answer, i tried but i didn't get good result , so now i know why it didn't work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can. I am not sure if it makes sense in your situation, so you'll have to analyze that, but if you want:

In the .h file

```
@interface MyView : UIView
{
    NSAutoReleasePool *pool;
}
// rest of view
```

In the .m file:

```
@implementation MyView

- (id) initXYZ // whatever initializer you have...
{
    self = [super init...];
    if (self)
    {
        pool = [[NSAutoReleasePool alloc] init];
        // rest of initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    // rest of dealloc
    [pool drain];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

As I said, I am not sure if it makes sense, unless you allocate lots of small objects in your view.